# How can I use VBA to concatenate 2 cells, and use string to populate a cell based on corresponding concatenation in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a single row for user inputs with the following fields:

| Project ID | Check Point | Task | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123456 | CP1 | T1 | 11/14/23 |

I then have another sheet with an Excel table with the following fields ("project." is the result of a Power Query query):

| project.Project_ID | project.City | project.State | Checkpoint | Task | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123456 | City | ST | CP1 | T14 |  |
| A123456 | City | ST | CP1 | T1 |  |

Here is the target outcome:

| project.Project_ID | project.City | project.State | Checkpoint | Task | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123456 | City | ST | CP1 | T14 |  |
| **A123456** | **City** | **ST** | **CP1** | **T1** | **11/14/23** |

What I'd like to do is have a VBA button for a user to click that will simply apply the date in the first table to the corresponding project_ID & task combination in the second table.

I have not attempted anything yet as my VBA knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 0):

- Assumes two tables starts from the first row and the first column on sheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim arrRes, rngRes As Range, arrData
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String
    Const SEP_CHAR = "|"
    Set Sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed
    Set Sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' Load data
    arrData = Sht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Set rngRes = Sht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrRes = rngRes.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through the first table
    For i = LBound(arrData)+1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1) & SEP_CHAR & arrData(i, 3)
        objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 4)
    Next i
    ' Loop through the 2nd table
    For i = LBound(arrRes)+1 To UBound(arrRes)
        sKey = arrRes(i, 1) & SEP_CHAR & arrRes(i, 5)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            ' Populate Data col
            arrRes(i, 6) = objDic(sKey)
        End If
    Next i
    rngRes.Value = arrRes
End Sub
```